# How can I add custom CSS to a Construct2 game?

Tags: construct-2, css

I am making a simple game using Construct2. My problem is that Construct2 provides basic HTML buttons, but I want to put a `background-image` on my buttons.

To do that, I want to add custom CSS to my project. But I am not finding any option to add CSS to my project. I have added the CSS in my files directory, but it doesn't automatically work so there must be something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a Construct2-specific way to do this; you just add and refer to the relevant CSS as you would any other HTML project. That is:

- Find the `<head>` element of the HTML page that you'd like to leverage your custom CSS in.
- Add `<link href="PATH-TO-STYLESHEET.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`, changing `PATH-TO-STYLESHEET` to refer to the CSS file you want to use (relative to the location of the containing HTML file).

You can find a more in-depth discussion, specific to Construct2, [here](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/60/construct2-how-to-customize-the-exported-html5-indexhtml/page-4)], though it essentially just repeats the above advice.

(There are of course other ways, such as leveraging inline CSS within `style` attributes of individual HTML elements, but the above is the more common technique and allows you to avoid a lot of repetition.)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. But
Finally I found the answer.. here is a plugin for construct 2 by using which we can import css to our construct 2 project..

https://www.scirra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=78007&start=0

Comment: That seems like it will work, but it likely just does a bunch of stuff for you automatically that you could do manually (see the guide I linked, from the same site).

Comment: yeah.. already tested it.. its working good... and yes.. looking to your link.. thanks